# How to send a warning message from Controller to View on Session Timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, signalr

Is it possible to send a message from controller to view on session timeout automatically? I've thought about using SignalR to accomplish this but can't fully understand it. Is there a way to do it(With or without SignalR)?

Comment: See [Handling Session and Authentication Timeouts in ASP.NET MVC](https://markfreedman.com/handling-session-and-authentication-timeouts-in-asp-net-mvc/). Do not use session state (different from authentication) unless you absolutely need it. See [Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/).

Comment: Yes, You can. InProc sessions are not good. You can send message in `global.asax` , `session_end` method to the user.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad I tried using the SernerState mode, but the session_end() is never invoked. session_end() seems to only work with the InProc mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using SignalR or an AJAX call is too complicated for you, there is another old fashioned way to do this, as this article from 2013 explains :

https://www.itworld.com/article/2832447/development/how-to-create-a-session-timeout-warning-for-your-web-application-using-jquery.html

First you need to know the exact time the session will expire, and then every time the page (view) is loaded just use a javascript timer to calculate whether the time is near or not.

Silly and not for all cases, but this is the simplest solution you may implement, before you step into SignalR or AJAX calls.

Hope it helps, btw.